# Access tables created in SAS Enterprise Guide Client into SAS Enterprise Miner Client?

Tags: sas

How can I access tables created in SAS Enterprise Guide Client into SAS Enterprise Miner Client?

Comment: This is an inappropriate place to ask this question. You need to deal with SAS directly or other forums directly related to utilizing SAS software.

Comment: Agree, now closed.

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree. We should cover statistics software here too. How many R questions are there?

Comment: There is an ongoing discussion about this question on meta: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/400/is-this-question-really-not-related-to-statistical-analysis

Comment: of course you need some software/tool and can't do all statistics by just using calculator. If this is not a valid question then why do tags like "R", "SAS" exists here?

Are you guys planning a new site for "Statistical Analysis Softwares"?

Comment: Reopened the question per this discussion: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/400/is-this-question-really-not-related-to-statistical-analysis

Comment: @Andy W., with all due respect, your immediate dismissal of this question is what I think is inappropriate. Numerous questions on this forum have to do with specific R package issues and no one closes them. SAS is used widely in business settings (much much more than R; I use both, and Python) and it seems useful to allow software related questions, given that software and analysis are so integral these days. If we are going to have such obvious double standards then the forum should be renamed "Statistical Analysis Using Open Source Software"

Comment: @Josh Hemann, this topic was discussed on meta  in the question Shane and Srikant linked to. If you have comments it would be useful to bring them up there. This question was re-opened so if you have an answer feel free to contribute.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously there is probably a better solution available than what I'm about to say - especially since these are both SAS products.  However but I think it bares saying that if all else fails, when your data is in a tabular structure, you can almost always export the data as a deliminated text file (e.g. csv) and import it into the new program as a deliminated text file.  I don't think I've seen a program that works with tablular data structures yet that doesn't provide these options.