# Counting how many times a package has been loaded in R?

Tags: r

Following [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1676/i-just-installed-the-latest-version-of-r-what-packages-should-i-obtain), I wish to have some way of counting how many times I am using a package in my daily work.

Is there a function/package to do that?

In case there isn't, how would you construct such a capability?

The way I would do that is by changing it so that at the end of any R session, a log file of the commands would be saved to some location.  On that file, I would grep out all instances of "library" and "require".  Then save the results into a file (with some time stamp).

Lastly, I might want some function to (once in X time) send this file to a remote FTP location - so that other R users could analyse the results.  (is there a way to do that with R ?!)

If someone wants to try and construct such a machanism - I'd be glad to help by providing a relevant FTP account and by spreading the word on it on ["R bloggers"](http://R-bloggers.com) for the good of the community.

p.s (mainly for Shane): I wasn't sure if this question should go on stackoverflow or here.  If this type of question wasn't debated yet on the meta.stat - it should be.  If it was, I'll be glad to know what the conclusion of that discussion was.

Comment: @Tal: I am basically happy to allow any R questions on here, but I just don't see how this has any relevance to the subject of data analysis.  This is a meta question about R itself, not even about using R.  We'll see what others think, but this seems more appropriate for stackoverflow, r-help, twitter, or a blog post.

Comment: Regarding how to do this: I would suggest making your own version of the `library` function that would track each package when you load it.

Comment: Related meta questions: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-to-answer-r-questions and http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169/is-it-possible-to-integrate-data-from-so-com-questions-tagged-r-here.

Comment: Lastly: regarding how to ftp; not sure how to do this from within an R function, but you can do it easily with `system("ftp ...")`.

Comment: Thanks Shane. I'll go through the threads.  You are correct, this is more of a R community topic then a statistical one - I'll vote to close the question (I don't erase it since it is an example of a "bad" question for this website)

Comment: Thanks @Tal.  This is similar in nature to this question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2269/access-tables-created-in-sas-enterprise-guide-client-into-sas-enterprise-miner-cl, which was also closed.

Comment: You should also reach out to @johnmyleswhite: http://twitter.com/johnmyleswhite/status/22395563278

Comment: If you were looking for gathering data on _installed_ packages, the crantastic package with its function crantastic.submitInstalledPackages would be worth looking at..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overload `library()` and `require()` so that they report what they do (whichever way: append to a text file, say) and have those replacement functions loaded first at startup.